# Retrieving the last record in each group - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

There is a collection of items with the following fields:

```
id   item_id  quantity    last_update
-------------------------------------------
1    111         10        2020-02-10 09:00:00
2    222         10        2020-02-10 09:00:00
2    222         15        2020-02-10 10:00:00
```

I want to retrieve the last updated record , for each group by id and item_id .
The results should be:

```
id   item_id  quantity    last_update
-------------------------------------------
1    111         10        2020-02-10 09:00:00
2    222         15        2020-02-10 10:00:00
```

If it was SQL , then i would do something like:

```
SELECT a.* FROM items a JOIN
( SELECT id ,item_id , max(last_update) as max_last_update
FROM items ) as b ON a.id=b.id AND a.item_id=b.item_id AND a.last_update=b.max_last_update
```

(or using self join) .

I'm new to mongoDB  , I did the inner query like:

```
inner_query = db.items.aggregate({ $group : { _id: {id:"$id" , item_id:"$item_id"}, max_last_update: { $max : "$last_update" }}})
```

How can I use inner_query var to get the expected results?
What is the equivalent in Mongo to JOIN or subquery?
(i'm using mongodb 4.0.4)

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "the last updated record for each group by **id and item_id**" then you should get all three documents.

Comment: You don't need a self join - neither in SQL nor in MongoDB

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $sort: { id: 1, item_id: 1, last_update: -1 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { id: "$id", item_id: "$item_id" },
         last_update: { $max: "$last_update" },
         quantity: { $first: "$quantity" },
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         last_update: 1,
         quantity: 1,
         id: "$_id.id",
         item_id: "$_id.item_id",
         _id: 0
      }
   }
])
```

Note, make proper `$sort`, otherwise `$frist` will return wrong value.